# MySQL update causes trigger but doesn't alter row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a PHP script that updates a row in a MySQL table. The table has triggers setup that store values in a second table on update.

I'm finding a strange issue where for a specific row, update statements do not change the row, but do hit the triggers and insert into the second table. I'm triggering on "after update" -- so I have no idea how data is not updated in the base table, but does successfully trigger "after update" and insert to the second table.

Any ideas on what scenario might cause this or where to troubleshoot?

EDIT:
To clarify further -- the UPDATE statement should alter the base table data, but is not. However, the trigger table target is reflecting a change as if the update had occurred. The trigger table is used as a logging table -- for any change to the base table, a snapshot of the data is inserted into the logging table via triggers. I'm seeing a record of the change in the logging table but no actual change in the base table.

Comment: Without a sample schema or a bit of context on the trigger this could be anything. Details matter here. Can you edit your question to provide more concrete information?

Comment: Did you check your trigger manually if runs correctly? Can you show here whats you've done?

Answer (score 1):

> for a specific row, update statements do not change the row, but do hit the triggers and insert into the second table.

That's normal.  `AFTER UPDATE` triggers still fire, even if the `UPDATE` doesn't modify the row because the data you tried to `SET` is already present.

If you want to know whether something thing changed, you have to test for it.

```
IF NOT (NEW.c1 <=> OLD.c1) THEN
  /* do stuff */
END IF;
```

Using `NOT ( ... <=> ... )` is a null-safe truthiness test with an inversion.  `NOT (NULL <=> 1)` evaluates to `TRUE` while `NULL != 1` evates to `NULL`.

Comment: My trigger already does a change comparison test. So to clarify -- the UPDATE statement is setting a value that should change the column data. That change is reflected in the trigger target table, but is not reflected in the base table.

Comment: @Michael, this issue is interesting. I can't believe it is really the expected behaviour. Now, since I need to have the trigger action happen ONLY when something has actually updated, what're my options? You'd agree with me that doing `IF NOT (NEW.c1 <=> OLD.c1) THEN` is a hell-hole when you have a hundred columns on the row!

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo yes, the update trigger fires for each row matched by the `WHERE` clause in an `UPDATE` query even if everything provided in `SET ...` matches the existing values in the row.  You can use the information in the `information_schema.columns` table to build the long expression that compares old and new values (not at runtime -- do this with a script to actually create the trigger body) or you can simply include the `SET` columns in `WHERE`, e.g. `UPDATE t1 SET c1 = 'foo', c2 = 'bar' WHERE id = 5 AND NOT (c1 <=> 'foo' AND c2 <=> 'bar');` The row doesn't match, so no trigger fires.